# Java: JButton and ArrayList: adding to JPanel from ArrayList

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jpanel, jbutton

So I'm getting a NullPointerException at Container.add so I'm obviously missing something I just don't see it. ArrayList is of Cell which extends JButton. The method init() is in an extended JPanel class. This is my frist question so be harsh on question format if I'm doing it wrong, Thank you.

```
    public void init() {
    int k = cells.length / 2;
    for (int i = 0; i < (cells.length / 2); i++) {
        int ID = rand.nextInt(25);
        cells[i] = new Cell(this, ID);
        cells[i + k] = new Cell(this, ID);
        k--;
        cellList.add(cells[i]);
        cellList.add(cells[i + k]);
    }

    Collections.shuffle(cellList);

    for (Cell cell : cellList) {
        add(cell);
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, something I noticed is that people don't seem to use debuggers anymore nowadays do they? I mean this was an obvious error, which easily can be overseen after long hours in front of the screen but debugging the code would have revealed the mistake in an instant. So please learn about debuggers and how to use them.

Comment: You're right. I'm new to programming and overlook the debugger frequently. I'm getting more familiar with NetBeans and it's debugger now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plain and simple don't `k--` before `cellList.add(cells[i+k])`

Even though I don't see what your are doing with the array anyways.

Answer (score 1):

What if `cells.length` is odd (not divisionable by 2, like 3, 5, 7, 15)

Consider that `cells.length=5`, then `k=2` and cells[4] will remain null.

Comment: valid point, but shouldn't matter since he wouldn't add `cells[4]` to `cellList`

Answer (score 0):

You're deprecating k before you add cells[i+k] to the cellList. As a result, cells[i+k] hasn't been initialized yet. Try changing it to:

```
    cellList.add(cells[i]);
    cellList.add(cells[i + k]);
    k--;
```

Comment: Whoops, was trying to bang out a quick answer before I left work and forgot to modify the original code after I copied and pasted. Sorry about that, answer edited.